# SQL Query to compare users by likes/dislikes

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I'm looking for some terms, or direction on this, not somebody to write the query. But I have no idea what question to be asking, or what jargon to research.

So I have a table, let's call it `reactions` and it holds three columns: users, post_id, and reaction as so:

```
user | post_id | reaction
1    | 23      | 1
1    | 24      | 0
2    | 15      | 0
3    | 16      | 0
4    | 17      | 1
3    | 14      | 0
2    | 23      | 1
2    | 12      | 1
1    | 17      | 0
```

How would I go about selecting a user that has the most reactions to posts in common with a given user?

For example, if knew user #5 a reaction of "1" to post "12" and a reaction of "0" to post "15" then I would find him comparable to user #2 who reacted the same way to those two data points.

Of course this would get more complicated as more users react to more posts, I would have to sort them by how well reactions align between users.

Anyways, thank you so much in advance for reading, and any help on where to read up on things would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just count the number of reactions in common using a self-join

```
select r.user, count(*)
from reactions r join
     reactions r2
     on r.post_id = r2.post_id and r.reaction = r2.reaction
where r2.user = @user
group by r.user
order by count(*) desc;
```

Comment: Whoa. And then I could just sort by count() DESC ?

Comment: Yep, you just set a record for "quickest to crush a question."
SO won't even let me accept it for 7 more minutes. Thank you. Be right back at you with a big green check.